# Dropdown menu not working on iPhone

Tags: javascript, ios, css, iphone, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to use a wordpress template for a wedding site and unfortunately i am getting no support from the author. The dropdown navigation menu is working correctly on windows in chrome/edge/etc... but it doesn't work on **iPhone** Safari. I am relatively a noob at css/javascript so i don't know where to start on debugging this one. I also don't have access to a mac to debug.

http://ndesaintheme.com/ulemulem/

The above link is the authors sample template which also exhibits the same behaviour.

Any tips on what might be the issue?

Peter

Comment: I managed to get hold of a mac and iPhone and try and test. I noticed that on the iPhone, once the menu is clicked to expand, the div container is strangely given a height of 1px. If I manually override it then the menu appears until I try toggle it off and then on again. After that I need to change the size to another value to force the redraw.

Comment: If you use class navbar instead navbar-right works.